# Writing webservice in php to retrieve the data corresponding to checked value in checkbox

Tags: php, android, web-services

I am very new to php. I have created an application in android. In that I have 5 check boxes and when I check any multiple check box I will pass the id of corresponding to web service.
like,  `http://192.168.0.150/neeraj/roammeo/service/listcat.php?cat_id=1,2,3`

Now, I want to retrieve that coma separated value in php web service and I want to print the corresponding data. I have written the code as,

```
<?php
include_once("webconfig.php");
include_once("webdatabase.php");
$cat_id = isset($_REQUEST['cat_id'])?trim($_REQUEST['cat_id']):"";
foreach($cat_id as $key => $value) 
{
echo "$key = $value\n";
}
$sql="select * from events join event_time join category on                          (events.event_id=event_time.event_id AND event_time.event_id=category.event_id) where           category.cat_id IN(1,2,3,5,6)";
$exe=$db->query($sql);
if($db->row_count()==0)
{
$xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>';
$xml .= '<root>';
$xml .= '<login>';
$xml .= '<all_events>';
$xml .= '<status>false</status>';
$xml .= "<message>No such event exist</message>";
$xml .= '</all_events>';
$xml .= '</login>';
$xml .= '</root>';
echo $xml;
}

else
{
$num = 1;
$xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>';
$xml .= '<root>';
$xml .= '<login>';
$xml .= '<all_events>';
$xml .= '<status>True</status>';
$xml .= "<message>success</message>";
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($exe))
{
$xml .= "<event$num>";
//$xml .= "<title>".$row['title']."</title>";
$xml .= "<location>".$row['location']."</location>
$xml .= "<start_date>".$row['start_date']."</start_date>";
$xml .= "<start_time>".$row['start_time']."</start_time>";
$xml .= "</event$num>";
$num++;
}
$xml .= '</all_events>';
$xml .= '</login>';
$xml .= '</root>';
echo $xml;
}
?>
```

I am getting error for it, I think query is the problem..In query I have joined 3 tables. I have retrieved the value from URL but I don't know how to use it in query to get the corresponding data based on checked check boxes.

Comment: Past resultant mysql query & erreor msg here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are sending your data as

```
http://192.168.0.150/neeraj/roammeo/service/listcat.php?cat_id=1,2,3
```

Your variable is not an array for you to iterate over using a foreach as you showing in your example code.

You can get the necessary array by either adjusting the PHP like so to satisfy the foreach

```
$cat_id = isset($_REQUEST['cat_id'])?explode(',' $_REQUEST['cat_id']):array();
```

Or you an adjust your request to send an array

```
http://192.168.0.150/neeraj/roammeo/service/listcat.php?cat_id[]=1&cat_id[]=2&cat_id[]=3
```

then alter your PHP to something like this

```
$cat_id = isset($_REQUEST['cat_id'])?$_REQUEST['cat_id']:array();
```

I can't help you much w/ the SQL queries because they are incomplete in your example.